# Git clean is not cleaning untracked files

Tags: git, git-clean

I'm getting the "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout...please move or remove them before you switch branches" error.

The common fix appears to be `git clean`

When I type that in, I get no error, but nothing happens. And when I go to check out another branch, I just get the same error as above.

Any reason as to why `git clean` would do absolutely nothing?

UPDATE:

More info. `git -n` and `git -f` do exactly the same...nothing.

Comment: `If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless given -f, -n or -i`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks. I updated my question. Alas, `-f` and `-n` also result in nothing happening.

Comment: what does `git status` show?

Comment: From which directory are you running `git clean`?  It will only clean the current working directory and below.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the root (of the project). I eventually was able to check out by forcing the checkout (`git checkout ... -f`) -- but still curious as to why git clean does nothing.

Comment: Are those files being ignored?  Did you try adding `-x`?

Answer (score 31):

If you want to clean untracked files, use the below command. But, take care before running this, as it will wipe your working area, index, HEAD.

```
git reset --hard
```

I think you are having untracked directories or ignored files(build files) of gitignore in your working area. you can remove them by the below command.

```
git clean -dfx
```

> -d
>
> Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an 
>   untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is
>   not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to
>   remove such a directory.
>
> -f
>   --force
>
> If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, 
>   git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless
>   given -f, -n or -i. Git will refuse to delete directories with .git
>   sub directory or file unless a second -f is given.
>
> -x
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) > and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore rules given with -e > options. This allows removing all untracked files, including build 
>   products. This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to 
>   create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.

For more information [git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)

Comment: I was missing that X... it wasn't cleaning =(

Comment: all of this is not helps(

Answer (score 13):

Like other comments have specified, you do need to add the -f flag.

But you may be having problems not because you aren't specifying --force, but rather because you're in a different subdirectory.

for example, if I have git repository residing in /myrepo/.git

and untracked files in subdirectory /myrepo/untracked/file.txt,

but my terminal's current working directory is /myrepo/src/.

git clean -fd will not work. You need to cd to the project root before running the command.

TL;DR: git clean -fd apparently only cleans untracked files and directories at and below your terminal's current working directory.

Comment: thanks! this was my issue (when working in a yarn workspace mono repo)

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly not what happened in OPs case. However I had the same problem. In my case the directory that wasn't cleaned was a submodule I added, but I subsequently git reset it. I had to remove all traces of it from `.gitmodules`, `.git/config` and `.git/modules/<path to submodule>` for git clean to remove it even if git status recognized it as untracked.

Comment: I was not able to run git clean (likely due to git module issues); I ended up doing: "rm -rf <folders containing the files>; git reset --hard"

Comment: In my case I moved some submodules using `git mv`. I couldn't find anything in `.gitmodules` or `.git` that looked like it should actually be removed, so I just removed those directories manually. Very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

try to Use

```
git clean -fd
```

Try stashing of the changes,

```
git stash
```

if you want to beck all the changes use,

```
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 2):

I always use `git clean -df -f` or `git clean -dfx -f` (if I wish to remove ignored files as well) as this is what the official docs for git say:

```
-f
--force
If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to  
false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless  
given -f or -i. Git will refuse to modify untracked nested git  
repositories (directories with a .git subdirectory) unless a second - 
f is given.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you need to specify -n or -f.  From the man pages:

```
OPTIONS

   -f, --force
       If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or
       directories unless given -f, -n or -i. Git will refuse to delete directories with .git sub directory or file unless a second
       -f is given.
```

Comment: I updated my question. Alas, `-f` and `-n` also result in nothing happening.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. In my case, I had to add *two* `-f` arguments to get all of my ignored files and directories deleted.

Answer (score 1):

My guess this is because `git clear -f` do not recurse into **untracked** directories even though the docs reads:

> Cleans the working tree by **recursively** removing files that are not under
> version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> ...

The `-d` docs clears up the confusion:

> Normally, when no <path> is specified, git clean will not recurse into untracked directories to avoid removing too much. Specify -d to have it recurse into such directories as well.
>
> ...